Eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of Laplacian with Neumann conditions
I'm working in the following problem
\begin{cases} -\Delta u = \lambda u, \text{ in } \Omega\\
   \partial_n u = 0, \text{ on } \partial\Omega
   \end{cases}
But I have some doubts.
The aim is prove that $L^2(\Omega)$ has an orthonormal basis $(u_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ consisting of Neumann eigenfunctions and the first eigenvalue is zero.
First, since the original problem is not well-posedness consider the following problem
\begin{cases} -\Delta u = \lambda u, \text{ in } \Omega\\
   \partial_n u = 0, \text{ on } \partial\Omega \\
    \overline{u} = 0
   \end{cases}
With $\overline{u}$ the mean value of $u$ in $\Omega$. We know, for the general problem, that if $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $\overline{f}=0$ (from compatibility condition), then exists a unique $u\in H^1(\Omega)$ with $\overline{u}=0$ such that is weak solution of Laplace Neumann homogeneous problem.
With this, we consider the following operator $B:F\to F$ where $F=\{f\in L^2(\Omega)\,:\, \overline{f}=0\}$ is a s.v.e and moreover a Hilbert space with same inner product. And $B$ is the operator that returns the weak solution of Laplace-Neumann problem. $B$ is also linear, continuos and compact operator (from Rellich theorem).
Later, since $B$ is also self-adjoint and positive definiteness from spectral theory we have a $(\mu_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of eigenvalues, positive and convergent to zero. And $(w_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of eigenfunctions such that is an orthonormal basis of $F$.
With $\lambda_n = \frac{1}{\mu_n}$, we have a sequence such that $\lambda_n \to +\infty$ the sequence of eigenvalues of Neumann problem and with same eigenfunctions found for $B$ we have the eigenfunctions of Neumann problem.
My question is how to reach the basis for $L^2$ and the first eigenvalue zero.
I was thinking about the fact that $L^2 = F \oplus F^{\perp}$ but I'm stuck in get an explicit form of $F^{\perp}$.
Is correct my path? Any suggestion?

The statement you make about from the compatibility condition you obtain a weak solution is incorrect. Assuming $\bar u=0$, the compatibility condition implies that there exists $v\in H^1(\Omega)$ such that $-\Delta v=\lambda u$ in $\Omega$ and $-\partial_nv=0$ on $\partial \Omega$. There is no reason why you should have $v=u$ from this argument. Indeed, if your argument were correct (so $v=u$), you would obtain an eigenfunction for all $\lambda \in \mathbb R$, so the spectrum would not be discrete
